# Finding All Types Created in a Haskell Repo

Tags: bash, haskell, ghci

Is there a way, using GHCi or even just Bash, to find a list of all types created (i.e., not imported from other libraries) in a Haskell repository?

**BONUS:** Could one also do something similar to get a list of all Haskell typeclasses created in a repo?

Comment: With types you mean `data X = ...` or also *type aliasses* (`type Foo = [Bar]`, etc.)?

Comment: All of them: `data` declarations, `newtype` declarations, `type` synonym declarations, and I'm sure I'm forgetting other ways to create types as well.

Comment: Would `egrep '^(data|newtype|type)\b' **/*.hs` work?  Kind of a blunt instrument, but should basically do the right thing…

Comment: As a first approximation that is good, but it doesn't capture generated types from C FFI generators, or Template Haskell, etc. It also doesn't capture types definitions that might be split across more than 1 line (although yes that is rare).

Comment: One could `:browse` each module from GHCi, but if there are many modules this could be cumbersome. Another option is to use haddock to generate the docs, and then read those. Both these methods will report about all the declared entities: types, bindings, classes, etc.

Comment: @chi: Does haddock generate docs for types that you haven't annotated and/or require lots of preparation before doc generation? Or is it automated to the point of only requiring a few commands?

Comment: @George It's been a while since I used it, but I think it collects everything exported (or with some hint, maybe more). If you don't annotate stuff you should still get the unannotated docs, I think.

Comment: Haddock generates documentation for all exported members of a module.

Comment: Just discovered a promising option to `haddock`, namely `--hoogle`. It will output haddock documentation in plain-text. Perhaps with a bit of hacking you could achieve what you want with this.

Comment: @chi: `:browse` will also output re-exported things, though – it gets you most of the way there, but not quite (or rather, but a little more)

Answer (score 1):

If you run `haddock --hoogle`, it will create a file with exactly one line per module, type, constructor, typeclass, instance, or function (including Template Haskell-generated definitions). So grepping for `^(data|type|newtype|class)` in its output should provide you with exactly what you are looking for.